# Storing time ranges as JSON?

Tags: postgresql

I have table with `jsonb` field - `timetable` which has next structure:

```
{
1: [{start:0, finish: 12}],
2: [{start:0, finish: 12}, {start:12, finish:17}],
3: [{start:12, finish: 17}],
4: [{start:0, finish: 12}],
5: [{start:12, finish:17}, {start:17, finish: 0}],
6: [{start:0, finish: 12}, {start:12, finish:17}],
7: [{start:17, finish: 0}]
}
```

1...7 are days of week, which represent when user is available - morning/afternoon/evening.
I'm doing filter where user could choose morning/afternoon/evening and days of week and get available users. If user checked all three time periods and all days I will have 21 variants. I wrote next query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
timetable <@ {1: [{start: 0, finish: 12}]} OR timetable <@ {1: [{start: 12, finish: 17}]} OR timetable <@ {1: [{start: 17, finish: 0}]} OR
timetable <@ {2: [{start: 0, finish: 12}]} OR timetable <@ {2: [{start: 12, finish: 17}]} OR timetable <@ {2: [{start: 17, finish: 0}]} OR
......
timetable <@ {7: [{start: 0, finish: 12}]} OR timetable <@ {7: [{start: 12, finish: 17}]} OR timetable <@ {7: [{start: 17, finish: 0}]}
```

Please advice me how to optimize my query. I know if user checked all possible periods and days I could just query with `timetable is not null`. But I want to optimize my task in general.

Comment: Why are you using JSON?

Comment: To expand a little on Jack's question, you have this beautiful highly efficient standard-compliant open-source relational DBMS called PostgreSQL. Why are you using JSON for data storage?

Comment: because postgresql works with jsonb:) This field is like of cache. User is available or not depends on 3 another entities and this field is result of computing.

Comment: You are not using it like cache though. You are trying to do queries against items/subparts stored inside the json value.

Comment: I use this field as way of denormalization to aggregate all data about user's availabilities to one field from different tables and make search by it. Maybe better choice will be new table.

Comment: If it is a bunch of data that needs to be retrieved as a unit or document, JSON might be the way forward. If not, the way to "optimize your task" for joins, filtering, etc is not to use JSON.

Comment: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Answer (score 3):

## Moving away from JSONB

JSONB is not the right tool for every job. I'm going to fix your schema because everyone here is about to cry.

Here we use an `ENUM` type and [`timerange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html)

```
CREATE TYPE dow AS ENUM (
  'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
  'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'
);

CREATE FUNCTION time_subtype_diff(x time, y time)
RETURNS float8 AS $$
  SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (x - y))
$$ LANGUAGE sql
STRICT IMMUTABLE;

CREATE TYPE timerange AS RANGE (
    subtype = time,
    subtype_diff = time_subtype_diff
);

CREATE TABLE available (
  user_id  int,  -- REFERENCES users,
  dow      dow,
  trange  timerange,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, dow)
);
```

now you can be sane (and we support minutes!)

```
CREATE TABLE users(user_id) AS VALUES (1::int);

INSERT INTO available VALUES 
  ( 1, 'Monday', '[13:42,16:12]' );

SELECT *
FROM users AS u
JOIN available AS a USING (user_id)
WHERE dow = 'Monday' AND a.trange @> '[14:00,15:00]';
```

Comment: What kind of index strategy its the best for this kind of custom enum type mixed with float, GIST maybe? @Evan Carroll

Comment: Yes, `CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;` and then create a gist index on `(user_id, dow, trange)`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its the best option, but my approach to this is in the past, is to transform the jsonb data into another more convenient data adapted to your query with a function and index it.

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION weekly_activity(timetable jsonb) RETURNS integer AS $$
    BEGIN
         IF timetable <@ {1: [{start: 0, finish: 12}]} OR timetable <@ {1: [{start: 12, finish: 17}]} THEN
           RETURN 111;
         END IF;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE; 

    CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_weekly_activity ON table BTREE( weekly_activity(timetable)) 

    SELECT * FROM table WHERE weekly_activity(timetable) = 111;
```

Silly example with just one case but you can adapt it to your situation.